# How to flatten a json field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading a json file with nested values. Here is how it loads:

```
>>> pd.read_json('/Users/david/Desktop/validate_headers/json/example_array2.json')
                                  address firstname   lastname  zip_code
0     {'state': 'MI', 'town': 'Dearborn'}    Jimmie  Barninger     12345
1  {'state': 'CA', 'town': 'Los Angeles'}      John        Doe     90027
```

I would like to flatten the nested object, so that my end dataframe looks like this:

```
firstname   lastname    zip_code    address.state   address.town
Jimmie      Barninger   12345       MI              Dearborn
John        Doe         90027       CA              Los Angeles
```

How would I do this, that is, if the dataframe column is an object, split that column up into multiple columns (and do so until there are no json objects left)?

Comment: what do you get if you do `type(df.loc[0, 'address'])`

Comment: @meW `object` but I also get that for most strings.

Comment: great then `ast.literal_eval()` is your saviour as explained by @anky_91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your `address` column is not a dictionary, you can convert to one by:

```
import ast
df.address = [ast.literal_eval(df.address[i]) for i in df.index]
```

then :

```
df.address.apply(pd.Series)

    state   town
0   MI  Dearborn
1   CA  Los Angeles
```

Though not sure about the length of your dataset, this can also be achieved by:

```
def literal_return(val):
try:
    return ast.literal_eval(val)
except (ValueError, SyntaxError) as e:
    return val
df.address.apply(literal_return)

>>%timeit [ast.literal_eval(df.address[i]) for i in df.index]
144 µs ± 2.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>%timeit df.address.apply(literal_return)
454 µs ± 4.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: that works great, though wouldn't this be quite slow if the objects are quite large and nested?

Comment: @anky_91 I agree on comprehensions, but I doubt on calling `ast` for every row. May be that will increase computational time. Not sure though.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for putting your efforts. I'm wondering if using `split` under `apply` could reduce the overhead. Thanks anyways for comparison.

Comment: @meW : went through some examples, I think this solution is taking lesser time than most,however would be really interested to know if we can do this faster. thanks for your time :)

Comment: I'll share my approach. Give me a while.

Comment: @anky_91 can you compare the performance of my approach and comprehension. I'd love to see the result.

Comment: `%timeit df.address.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].replace("'","").replace("}",""))`  gives me `355 µs ± 9.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: great, that tells everything. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 8):

much simpler:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': [{'state': 'MI', 'town': 'Dearborn'} , {'state': 'CA', 'town': 'Los Angeles'}], 'name':['John', 'Jane']})

df = df.join(df['address'].apply(pd.Series))
```

then

```
df.drop(columns='address')
```

Comment: maybe. but if you load json with the pd.read_json, it's an object, not a string.
if you want to parse json strings too, just `.apply(json.loads, axis=1)`

Comment: to me the comment says: '@meW object but I also get that for most strings.' 
that means he gets the 'Object' type for most strings too. doesn't necessarilly mean he actually has strings representation of json

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `apply`:

```
df['city'] = df.address.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].replace("'","").replace("}",""))
df['state'] = df.address.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1].split(':')[1].replace("'","").replace("}",""))
df.drop(columns=['address'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below ([reference](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas))

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```